# Shelosha Asar Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred thirteen?

### ?שלושה עשר ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 313.

Lazy gematria doesn't come close to real achievment.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred twelve entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Shabbos prior to Rosh Chodesh Nissan or the Shabbos of Rosh Chodesh Nissan is known as Parshas HaChodesh. We read for the Maftir in Parshas Bo [Shemos 12 Posuk 1 - 20](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0212.htm). This reading contains **313** words.

Comment: +1. Note that this counts words connected by a _makaf_ as separate words (as we usually count them, so "אֶל־מֹשֶׁה" counts as two).

Answer (score 0):

[Encyclopedia Britannica's](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/266851/Samson-Raphael-Hirsch) entry regarding Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch has **313** words.

Comment: Heh. Nice try! 8^)